# PHP/Wordpress: IF/ELSE executing both conditions

Tags: php, wordpress

Have been reading through multiple similar questions and went over my syntax many times, but I can't figure out why my PHP code is executing both conditions.

I'm trying to replace the url of an element with the string from a custom field if the field is not empty. If the field is empty, I want to output the permalink normally. What happens is that the code concatenates both the string from the custom field and the permalink when the field is not empty. If i remove the string in the field, it works fine.

```
<div class="profile-content">
     <a href="
            <?php 
                if ( the_field('direct_resource_link') != '') {
                     the_field('direct_resource_link'); 
                } else { 
                the_permalink($id);
                } ?>

                "><h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5></a>
    <div class="profile-footer">
```

Thanks!
Dan.

Comment: `the_field('direct_resource_link')` will run the moment you check your condition (*how else is it supposed to know the return value?*) and it returns `''`. The internal condition call is unnecessary as `the_field` has already run with the exact same arguments. I have no idea where `the_field` is from though - it's not a WP function (probably [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/)?).

Comment: yup, it's from ACF, it just returns the value of that field. I removed the internal condition call and it works as before - thanks! However, the problem described persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT after comment from original poster**

My initial assessment (left below for reference) was correct. You are using function that will `print`/`echo` content instead of `return`ing it. Your if will always evaluate to false, because you are calling function that returns nothing; and PHP thinks that nothing and empty string are the same thing.

You didn't see that when field was empty, because `the_field()` for empty field printed empty string (or nothing at all), i.e. it didn't modify value printed by `the_permalink()` in any way/

According to [ACF documentation](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/), `the_field()` is accompanied by [`get_field()`](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) which returns value instead of printing it.

Your code should look like that:

```
<div class="profile-content">
     <a href="
            <?php 
                if ( get_field('direct_resource_link') ) {
                     the_field('direct_resource_link'); 
                } else { 
                     the_permalink($id);
                } ?>

                "><h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5></a>
    <div class="profile-footer">
```

### My initial post

What happens is that you run function `the_field('direct_resource_link')` and compare it's return value to ''; if that value is empty, you run `the_permalink($id);`.

It's hard to tell what `the_field()` is and what it is supposed to do, but I guess that it `print`s value instead of `return`ing it. So if field is empty, it prints nothing, resulting in pure run of `the_permalink()`. If field is not empty, it prints it content and returns nothing. Since nothing is equal to empty string, PHP proceeds with `else` branch and invokes `the_permalink()` that prints additional info.

Solution: modify `the_field()` to return value instead of printing it, or make additional function that will query for value and return it, and use that function in if statement.

Comment: If the code is following the scheme WordPress is using, there might already be a "get_the_field()" function that returns the value. Might be worth checking beforehand...

Comment: Thanks guys - the_field() is coming from advanced custom fields as described here http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/ . That is indeed the functionality I'm looking to implement, it the_field(direct_resource_link) is empty, then (and only then) run the_permalink().

Comment: as per your suggestions, ACF had get_field(). This worked for me: `<?php $value = get_field( "direct_resource_link" ); if( $value ) { echo $value;  } else { the_permalink($id);} ?>`

Answer (score 1):

[Miroslaw Zalewski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3552063/miros%c5%82aw-zalewski) already answered your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32684276/247893), so this is simply to show you the kind of code needed to fix your issue:

```
function get_the_field($field) {
    ob_start();
    the_field($field);
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

This code will start an output buffer (which will capture all echo'd data), run `the_field` and return (and delete) the output buffer (the echo'd data from `the_field`). This means you can simply do the following:

```
...
<?php 
    $theField = get_the_field('direct_resource_link');

    if ( $theField != '') {
         echo $theField; 
    } else { 
        the_permalink($id);
    } 
?>
...
```

Comment: Thank you - after Miroslaw's explanation, i managed to figure it out using the ACF get_field() (see below as answer to his comment). Edited as solution to my question since you've done a great job at explaining and formatting it! Thanks again!

Comment: Output buffer should be used as a last resort in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This can all be simplified. `the_field()` echoes a meta value. You don't want that...Instead, you want to `return` the value to check it, before conditionally echoing it. You can do this using `get_field()`.

In the simplest form, your final code would look like the following:

```
<a href="<?php get_field('direct_resource_link') ? the_field('direct_resource_link') : the_permalink($id); ?>">
    <h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
</a>
```